# how to get data from combobox and save it in database

Tags: php, html, css

> Add Span in php
>
> this part work fine

```
<select id="selectbasic" name="country" class="form-control">
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "gocall");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Échec de la connexion : %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
   
    if ($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT country_name FROM country ")) {
        $row= mysqli_num_rows($result);
        while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $id=$row[0];
            echo" <option value=\"FR\">$id</option>";
        }
    }
?>
</select>
       

************************************************************************
```

Save combobox in database

> Here is the error

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['addcustomer'])) {
        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];
        $country=$_POST['country'];
           
        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "db1");
           
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            printf("Échec de la connexion : %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }
        $req="INSERT INTO customer 
                VALUES (NULL,'$name','$lastname','$email','$password',$country)";
        $mysqli->query($req);
        $mysqli->close();
    }
?>
```

Comment: This should always be your first attempt at debugging! Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: check your country field type in database . in your dropdown country field is string and in your insert query you haven't appended single quote(') for $country.

Comment: **WHY** make a mess of your question again after I formatted it so it was readable

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?php
                            ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
                            if (isset($_POST['addcustomer']))
                            {
                                $name=$_POST['name'];
                                $lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
                                $email=$_POST['email'];
                                $password=$_POST['password'];
                                $country=$_POST['country'];

                   $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "db1");

                                if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                                    printf("Échec de la connexion : %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
                                    exit();
                                }
                                $req="INSERT INTO customer VALUES (NULL,'$name','$lastname','$email','$password','$country')";
                                $mysqli->query($req);
                                $mysqli->close();
                            }
                            ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

your drop down should be like ;

```
 <select id="selectbasic" name="country" class="form-control">
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "gocall");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Échec de la connexion : %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    if ($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT country_id,country_name FROM country ")) {
        $row= mysqli_num_rows($result);
        while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $id=$row['country_id'];
            $country_name=$row['country_name'];
            echo" <option value='$id'> $country_name </option>";
        }
    }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Better, but how do you know that the OP has a column in that table called `country_id`

Comment: i hope he have it.otherwise he has to save $country in string not directly like  $req="INSERT INTO customer VALUES (NULL,'$name','$lastname','$email','$password',$country)";

Comment: @VibhaBharwad This is a _rabbit hole question_ There are just too many issues with the OP's code and not enough information to even guess at the correct solution. A total rewrite is basically all that can be done, after some examination of the books/tutorials. _I suggest you cut your losses and run for the hills_ This will take you hours to get all the information you need to rewrite this for the OP